# "order by" postgres and oracle have different results

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by

when I do "order by" with the varchar field in the oracle database
Here is the result
DATA:

```
1>33
1>31>33
1>31
112
11
1
```

Is there any way to achieve the desired result below
DATA:

```
112
11
1>33
1>31>33
1>31
1
```

for postgres it works perfectly but for other databases it is not working as it should

If someone can help me, thank you very much

Oracle_19

[image]

Postgres_13

[image]

source:

```
create table test(
data char(50)
)

insert into test values('112');
insert into test values('11');
insert into test values('1>33');
insert into test values('1>31>33');
insert into test values('1>31');
insert into test values('1');

select * from test order by data desc
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I need the solution for oracle

Comment: Cannot replicate your output for [Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bc54e6f782289626eaafbdb0127e04d2) or [PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=bc54e6f782289626eaafbdb0127e04d2); they both appear to output the same order.

Comment: _"for postgres it works perfectly but for other databases it is not working as it should"_   If postgres is the outlier, then perhaps it is "other databases" for which it "works perfrectly" and and it is postgres that "is not working as it should".  But as @MT0 said, he cannot replicate.  Perhaps you give us a reproducible test case - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @MT0 I have provided my screenshots and sources

Comment: @EdStevens  Yes, thank you for prompting me to provide more information

Comment: Can you reproduce the results you get in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13

Comment: @forpas  Here is my regeneration result  [Oracle ](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=59a5355a79625a70f7c7748487c76ca7) and [PostgreSQL  ] (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=448d58e4cdcfc5fd84b95956eb727d27)

Comment: So PostgreSQL's results are identical to oracle's.

Comment: @forpas I am really confused that the results of postgres on my machine are different from those on dbfiddle even though they are the same postgres version 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't pretend to have a lot of knowledge of collation, but you can achieve the result you want in Oracle with [UCA collation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/linguistic-sorting-and-matching.html#GUID-6ADFC7B7-5857-4962-BED9-E1975CEDD0C8) and [variable characters and weighting](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/linguistic-sorting-and-matching.html#GUID-5E5AC1FF-1E02-406B-82E1-94521D695C96), either for a specific query with `nlssort()`:

```
select * from test order by nlssort(data, 'NLS_SORT=UCA0700_DUCET_VN') desc
```

or by setting the NLS_SORT session (or system) parameter:

```
alter session set nls_sort = UCA0700_DUCET_VN;
select * from test order by data desc
```

Both give the result you want:

```
DATA
----------
112                                               
11                                                
1>33                                              
1>31>33                                           
1>31                                              
1
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9bcc1902cc362e0822112315ab110e7d)

Presumably your PostgreSQL environment is configured to do something similar.

---

Never used PostgreSQL but looks like this collation does the same:

```
select * from test order by data collate "vi-VN-x-icu" desc
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b7d9bac93953f115bc8ab4a8aa937551)

Comment: Great friend, I appreciate your help, it worked well for me, thank you so much